# android custom view ondraw, get bitmap from canvas?

Tags: java, android, view, android-framelayout

So I seem to have a conundrum. I need to add multiple custom views to a framelayout. The code for this is working just fine. However, I wish to access the underlying bitmap that the canvas uses in the views onDraw method. Like this one (in a class that extends View):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawARGB(Color.alpha(bgColor), Color.red(bgColor),
            Color.green(bgColor), Color.blue(bgColor));
    m.reset();
    m.setTranslate(imgPosX - ((float) userImage.getWidth() / 2.0f), imgPosY
            - ((float) userImage.getHeight() / 2.0f));
    m.postRotate(angle);
    m.postScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
    canvas.drawBitmap(userImage, m, null);
    }
```

I wish to erase certain pixels essentially. Now, I know I can do this via the setPixel method which is fine but it is exceptionally slow and not satisfactory. I have a working ndk function that does exactly what I want, but it passes in a bitmap. I know I can use a SurfaceView instead of a View to access the bitmap like that, however as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/COffLpanlz0/discussion) multiple SurfaceViews in a FrameLayout isn't an option. So, I would think I need to manipulate the bitmap itself used by the canvas in the onDraw method. How would I go about doing this? or alternatively I don't mind creating another bitmap, passing it into the ndk function and returning/drawing that, however would I do a canvas.drawBitmap with transparent pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into setting the PorterDuff mode on a Paint object?
use `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR))` then draw over the pixels that you want to erase

edit: What exactly are you trying to clear? There are [multiple modes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) and you may need to select a different one depending on what you are trying to do. Here is an example of a function I currently use to crop Bitmaps to a circle.

```
public static Bitmap crop_circle_center(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final int diameter = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(diameter,
            diameter, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    rect.offset(-(bitmap.getWidth()-diameter)/2, -(bitmap.getHeight()-diameter)/2);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(diameter/ 2, diameter/ 2,
            diameter / 2, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, paint);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: if I make a blank bitmap, apply ONLY transparent pixels, then come back and drawbitmap with porterduff, would it set only the pixels I've changed in the new bitmap to transparent on the canvas?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to clear? Do you have an example of a before and after image?

Comment: I ended up just making a second Canvas, manipulating that one, then drawing the bitmap from that one to the main canvas, did the trick ^_^